# Error when I copy sheets from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I've just see many articles but I haven't found the answer to my problem.

I must copy one sheet from file A into file B. When the program copies the sheets I have the `error 10040`.

The code is below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim numsheets As Integer
Dim nmp As Integer
Dim WB As Workbook 'Is the target workbook
Dim WB_prov As Workbook 'Is the source workbook
Dim SH As Worksheet
Dim SH_prov As Worksheet 'Is the sheet to copy
Dim CurrentSN As String 'Is the name of the sheets to import

Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set SH = WB.ActiveSheet

'Open the source file
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set App = New Excel.Application
Set WB_prov = App.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\roberto\Documents\tav7_2017_7.xlsm")
Set sh1 = WB_prov.Sheets("TabellaMansioni")

'Read number of sheets to insert
NumMan = SH.Range("A31")
RR1 = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows



'Primo controllo sull'esistenza dei codici
For i = 2 To (2 + NumMan)
    For j = 2 To RR1
        If SH.Range("B" & i) = sh1.Range("B" & j) Then
        Else
            MsgBox ("Il codice non è presente in archivio.")
            GoTo Chiusura
        End If
    Next
Next

**'Insert sheets
For i = 2 To (2 + NumMan)
    CurrentSN = SH.Range("B" & i).Value
    Set SH_prov = WB_prov.Sheets(CurrentSN)
    SH_prov.Copy After:=WB.Sheets("Riepilogo") *'In this line error 1004*
Next**
```

Have you any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Does a sheet by the name of "Riepilogo" exist in the ActiveWorkbook?

Comment: Yes in the ActiveWorkbook the sheet "Riepilogo" exist

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added `Option Explicit` at the top of your module so it's allowed you to create variables on the fly (i.e. not declaring them first).
e.g. You've declared `SH` as a worksheet, in the code you seem to swap between using `sh1` and `SH`.  You've not declared `App`, `NumMan`, `sh1`, `RR1`, `i` and `j`.

*I reckon this is the bit that's stopping your code from working*:
You've created a new instance of Excel using `Set App = New Excel.Application` so the two workbooks are in different instances.

Without testing:

- I'd get rid of the line `Set App = New Excel.Application`
- Change
  `Set WB_prov = App.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\roberto\Documents\tav7_2017_7.xlsm")` to
  `Set WB_prov = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\roberto\Documents\tav7_2017_7.xlsm")`

A basic example of copying a sheet from one workbook to another:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim WB_prov As Workbook
    Dim SH_prov As Worksheet

    Set WB = ThisWorkbook 'The workbook containing the code.
    Set SH = WB.Worksheets(1) 'Reference to first sheet in tab order.

    Set WB_prov = Workbooks.Add 'This will be created in the same instane of Excel as WB.
    Set SH_prov = WB_prov.Worksheets(1)
    SH_prov.Name = "UniqueName"

    'Copy UniqueName from the new workbook to after the first worksheet in the WB workbook.
    SH_prov.Copy After:=SH

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. In this way the program work fine. But the program don't work (return 1004 erro) if the "source" file  (WB_prov) is in a Server. Why this?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference where the file is unless there's some kind of permission problem on the server.  If you enter `workbooks.Open("S:\Somewhere_On_Server\tav7_2017_7.xlsm")` in the immediate window does it open the file?

Comment: no the file doesn't open. But if I insert the line `Set App = New Excel.Application`  and put `Set App = New Excel.Application
Set WB_prov = App.Workbooks.Open("S:\Somewhere_On_Server\tav7_2017_7.xlsm")` the file open correctly but I after I have the error 1004 when copy the sheets in the target workbook like my first post